# C: How to get a 4096 bit prime number?

Tags: c, cryptography

How to get a random, really big (f.e. 4096 bit) prime number in C?
Does anyone know a good Library for this?

Comment: Not what you ask for, but might interest you as well: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/71/405

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best bet is [libgmp](https://gmplib.org/).

It has a function that will scan for the next prime number (using [Miller-Rabin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test)) starting from some starting number.

```
void mpz_nextprime ( mpz_t rop, mpz_t op );
```

> Set rop to the next prime greater than op.
>
> This function uses a probabilistic algorithm to identify primes. For practical purposes it's adequate, the chance of a composite passing will be extremely small.

Is the function you want.

You just roll a random number with as many bits as you need and then fire `mpz_nextprime`. Runtime should be somewhere around `O(log(op))` (probabilistic).

You will also need one of the [random number generators](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/mkl/gnump/integer_random_numbers.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Generally you generate a large random number, using a strong random number generator (e.g. on Windows use `CryptGenRandom`), then apply some checks to determine whether it is likely to be prime.

The only way to check that it really is prime is to try dividing by every number between 1 and (potential-prime / 2). If any of them divides equally with no remainder, it's not prime. Since that will take an infeasibly long time to compute (that's the whole point of using really big prime numbers), the tests used are far simpler and based on the probability that the number is unlikely to have easily guessable factors.

If you're implementing software that uses encryption, I *strongly* recommend that you use a NIST-certified cryptographic library or module to generate your keys and do the encryption.

Comment: I'm far from being a crypto expert, but at least one of NIST RNG algorithms (`Dual_EC_DRBG`) is **known** to have a backdoor. Not saying that others don't have such a backdoor, but I'm not sure I would recommend it.

Comment: check between 1 and sqrt(potential-prime)

Comment: @BinyaminSharet Yeah, so don't use the bcrypt libraries from RSA. Most hash based libs should be safe though. Dual EC was a bit suspect from the start - nobody really needs EC crypto to create a random generator.

Comment: Attempting to divide by every number between 1 and half the candidate is not the only way to check that a number is prime.

Comment: The infeasibility of testing a number for primality is not the point of using prime numbers. It is the infeasibility of factoring that is desired. “In theory” it could be possible to determine nearly instantly whether a particular number is prime or not yet still difficult to find the two primes that are factors of a particular large number.